# Firefox crashing Linux Mint 20 (ulyan) memory thrashing

Tags: linux-mint, memory, firefox, out-of-memory

Firefox 105.0.1 eats all my memory (mate-system-monitor reports 100%), regularly crashing Linux Mint 20 (ulyan), typically several times a week.

My system completely locks up, mouse and keyboard become unresponsive, hitting `<ctrl>+<alt>+<F5>` doesn't work.

Mint is surely at fault: Operating systems must insulate against poorly written software that exhausts memory.

Earlier versions of Mint / Firefox didn't suffer this problem.

What can be done?

UPDATE: Upgrading to Linux Mint 20.3 didn't solve.

Comment: Which version of Firefox? If you could provide some stats on memory usage, that might help. How does it crash? Is it responsive to the network, can you ping it, ssh into it?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to **Linux Mint 21 solved**.

Another useful solution: **magic SysRq key**, `<alt> + <print screen> + <f>` instructs the kernel to invoke the *Out of Memory (OOM) Killer*, to enable edit `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` and ensure `kernel.sysrq` includes `64`, e.g., kernel.sysrq=438 doesn't include 64, it's the sum 256+128+32+16+4+2, whilst `kernel.sysrq=502` does.

Answer (score -1):

Not the OS's fault. You have a bad physical memory.

Install and run `memtester` to check the RAM.

Comment: This problem recently emerged---previous versions of Linux Mint didn't exhibit this problem.

Comment: Unsure why this answer has been downvoted, seems like a legit remark, albeit less likely than other issues: Downvoter, why?